# OpenGL C++ create a filter lens over image

Tags: c, opengl, glut

```
//Aplicatia realizeaza deschiderea si afisarea unui fisier tga


#include "glos.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <glaux.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PI 3.14
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    GLbyte  identsize;              // Size of ID field that follows header (0)
    GLbyte  colorMapType;           // 0 = None, 1 = paletted
    GLbyte  imageType;              // 0 = none, 1 = indexed, 2 = rgb, 3 = grey, +8=rle
    unsigned short  colorMapStart;          // First colour map entry
    unsigned short  colorMapLength;         // Number of colors
    unsigned char   colorMapBits;   // bits per palette entry
    unsigned short  xstart;                 // image x origin
    unsigned short  ystart;                 // image y origin
    unsigned short  width;                  // width in pixels
    unsigned short  height;                 // height in pixels
    GLbyte  bits;                   // bits per pixel (8 16, 24, 32)
    GLbyte  descriptor;             // image descriptor
} TGAHEADER;

void  cerc(GLint radius)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    for (double i = 0; i < 2 * PI; i += PI / 30)
        glVertex3f(cos(i) * radius, sin(i) * radius, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

}

GLbyte *gltLoadTGA(const char *szFileName, GLint *iWidth, GLint *iHeight, GLint *iComponents, GLenum *eFormat)
    {
    FILE *pFile;            // File pointer
    TGAHEADER tgaHeader;        // TGA file header
    unsigned long lImageSize;       // Size in bytes of image
    short sDepth;           // Pixel depth;
    GLbyte  *pBits = NULL;          // Pointer to bits

    // Default/Failed values
    *iWidth = 0;
    *iHeight = 0;
    *eFormat = GL_BGR_EXT;
    *iComponents = GL_RGB8;

    // Attempt to open the file
    pFile = fopen(szFileName, "rb");
    if(pFile == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Read in header (binary)
    fread(&tgaHeader, sizeof(TGAHEADER), 1, pFile);


    // Get width, height, and depth of texture
    *iWidth = tgaHeader.width;
    *iHeight = tgaHeader.height;
    sDepth = tgaHeader.bits / 8;
    printf ("read file %d\n",tgaHeader.height);
    // Put some validity checks here. Very simply, I only understand
    // or care about 8, 24, or 32 bit targa's.
   // if(tgaHeader.bits != 8 && tgaHeader.bits != 24 && tgaHeader.bits != 32)
   //    return NULL;

    // Calculate size of image buffer
    lImageSize = tgaHeader.width * tgaHeader.height * sDepth;
    printf ("read file %d\n",lImageSize);
    // Allocate memory and check for success
    pBits = (GLbyte*)malloc(lImageSize * sizeof(GLbyte));
    if(pBits == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Read in the bits
    // Check for read error. This should catch RLE or other 
    // weird formats that I don't want to recognize
    if(fread(pBits, lImageSize, 1, pFile) != 1)
        {
        free(pBits);
        return NULL;
        }

    // Set OpenGL format expected
    switch(sDepth)
        {
        case 3:     // Most likely case
            *eFormat = GL_BGR_EXT;
            *iComponents = GL_RGB8;
            break;
        case 4:
            *eFormat = GL_BGRA_EXT;
            *iComponents = GL_RGBA8;
            break;
        case 1:
            *eFormat = GL_LUMINANCE;
            *iComponents = GL_LUMINANCE8;
            break;
        };


    // Done with File
    fclose(pFile);

    // Return pointer to image data
    return pBits;
    }



GLbyte* pImage = NULL;
GLint iWidth, iHeight, iComponents;
GLenum eFormat;

void fire() {
    // Targa's are 1 byte aligned
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);


    pImage = gltLoadTGA("fire.tga", &iWidth, &iHeight, &iComponents, &eFormat);


    glRasterPos2i(0, 0);

    // Draw the pixmap
    if (pImage != NULL)
        glDrawPixels(iWidth, iHeight, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImage);

    // Don't need the image data anymore
    free(pImage);

}
void lion() {
    // Targa's are 1 byte aligned
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    pImage = gltLoadTGA("lion.tga", &iWidth, &iHeight, &iComponents, &eFormat);


    glRasterPos2i(0, 0);

    // Draw the pixmap
    if (pImage != NULL)
        glDrawPixels(iWidth, iHeight, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImage);

    // Don't need the image data anymore
    free(pImage);

}
int refreshmill = 1;

void timer(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(refreshmill, timer, 0);
}

GLfloat dirx = 200;
GLfloat diry = 200;


void display(void)
    {

    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    glClearStencil(0x00);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0x01, 0x03);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0x01, 0x03);


    lion();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0x01, 0x03);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(dirx, diry, 0);
    cerc(100);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0x01, 0x03);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);



    fire();


    glutSwapBuffers();
    }


void SpecialKeyHandler(int key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP )
        diry += 10.0f;

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN )
        diry -= 10.0f;

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        dirx += 10.0f;

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        dirx -= 10.0f;
}

void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
    {
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Reset the coordinate system before modifying
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set the clipping volume
    gluOrtho2D(0.0f, (GLfloat) w, 0.0, (GLfloat) h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();    
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main program entrypoint
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 640);
    glutCreateWindow("Proiect");
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKeyHandler);

    glutReshapeFunc (myReshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
    }
```

So basically, this program loads a TGA image, and applies some filters. The filters are applied on the whole image, but i would like to create a lens like shape ( a circle ) over the image and apply those filters only inside that circle.

[This is the result now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9HT1.png)
[image]

[And i would like to make it look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9uBl.png)
[image]

How can i do this?

Edit: Ok now i have the circle shape which i can move. I'm working on the filters now but the problem is that they are applied on both images not only on the image inside the circle.

Comment: I suggest to switch to "modern" OpenGL an to use a [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader)

Comment: "`#pragma pack(1)`" - while that may save a tiny bit of memory, it will most likely slow down access to member variables significantly. Why do you do that? Is memory use *really* that important to you? Reordering your structure members to minimize padding and leaving out the `pragma` would probably be the best of both worlds.

Comment: `typedef struct { ... } TGAHEADER;` - So very *C*. That's usually not how you'd do it in C++. What language are you actually using?

Comment: "`#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>`" - In C++ you'd want those to be `#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP can’t reorder that structure, it was defined more than 30 years ago. Here’s my version, BTW: https://github.com/Const-me/nanovg/blob/master/src/FontStash2/truevision.cpp#L22-L36

Comment: My mistake, the tag should be C instead of C++ i will correct it. @Rabbid76 it is a homework so i can't really use something else. I'm thinking about using the stencil test. Display the original image, then use the stencil test so i can display the same image filtered inside a circle shape. So it's basically an ilusion. But i'm failing to do it.